# Inline MSIL/CIL

Tags: c#, inline, cil

I created following simple method:

```
public static void Main () {
    Console.WriteLine("Hello world!");
    Console.ReadKey(true);
}
```

Then I used ILSpy to get the MSIL code:

```
.method public hidebysig static void Main() cil managed {
    .entrypoint
    .maxstack  8
    nop
    ldstr "Hello world!"
    call void [mscorlib]System.Console::WriteLine(string)
    nop
    ldc.i4.1
    call valuetype [mscorlib]System.ConsoleKeyInfo [mscorlib]System.Console::ReadKey(bool)
    pop
    ret
}
```

Finally I tried to write the MSIL code into my C# code using the `#if IL` trick that I've found [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/438868/Inline-MSIL-in-Csharp-VB-NET-and-Generic-Pointers).

```
public static void Main () {
    #if IL
        nop
        ldstr "Hello world!"
        call void [mscorlib]System.Console::WriteLine(string)
        nop
        ldc.i4.1
        call valuetype [mscorlib]System.ConsoleKeyInfo [mscorlib]System.Console::ReadKey(bool)
        pop
        ret
    #else
        Console.WriteLine("Hello world!");
        Console.ReadKey(true);
    #endif
}
```

I tried this trick with and without the `nop`s and with and without the `#else`, but Visual Studio never compiled the MSIL code. Where is my mistake or is there another way (if there is a way) to write MSIL code into C# code?

Comment: Did you run their build tool?

Comment: Do you mean InlineILCompiler.exe? I just found it :D

Comment: Just out of curiosity what were you trying to achieve here?